# how to analyze the value of tfidf matrix in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, k-means, tf-idf

I am using sklearn's KMeans algorithm for document clustering as guided in 
http://brandonrose.org/clustering

Here is a calculation of the TFIDF matrix. I have understood the concept behind the TFIDF technique but when I print this matrix the matrix is this:

```
  (0, 11)   0.238317554822
  (0, 34)   0.355850989305
  (0, 7)    0.355850989305
  (0, 21)   0.238317554822
  (0, 16)   0.355850989305
  (0, 35)   0.355850989305
  (0, 8)    0.355850989305
  (0, 17)   0.355850989305
  (0, 36)   0.355850989305
  (1, 11)   0.238317554822
  (1, 21)   0.238317554822
  (1, 23)   0.355850989305
  (1, 0)    0.355850989305
  (1, 24)   0.355850989305
  (1, 12)   0.355850989305
  (1, 22)   0.355850989305
  (1, 25)   0.355850989305
  (1, 13)   0.355850989305
  (2, 2)    0.27430356415
  (2, 18)   0.339992197465
  (2, 26)   0.339992197465
  (2, 39)   0.339992197465
  (2, 3)    0.339992197465
  (2, 19)   0.339992197465
  (2, 27)   0.339992197465
  (2, 4)    0.339992197465
  (2, 20)   0.339992197465
  (3, 2)    0.27430356415
  (3, 40)   0.339992197465
  (3, 9)    0.339992197465
  (3, 1)    0.339992197465
  (3, 5)    0.339992197465
  (3, 41)   0.339992197465
  (3, 10)   0.339992197465
  (3, 6)    0.339992197465
  (3, 42)   0.339992197465
  (4, 11)   0.202877476983
  (4, 21)   0.202877476983
  (4, 28)   0.302932576437
  (4, 31)   0.302932576437
  (4, 37)   0.302932576437
  (4, 14)   0.302932576437
  (4, 29)   0.302932576437
  (4, 32)   0.302932576437
  (4, 38)   0.302932576437
  (4, 15)   0.302932576437
  (4, 30)   0.302932576437
  (4, 33)   0.302932576437
```

What do the values in this matrix representing? can anybody that worked on this help me to understand this?

Comment: What is your first row ? can you show us how is your text corpus (the input of your TFIDF) ?

Comment: This is my sample corpus data 
 ["java is platform independent language",
   "learning java language is awasome","eclipse juno is the new release","eclipse is successfully installed in my computer","java is object oriented programming language"]

Comment: is the matrix shown the whole matrix obtained or just a snippet of it ?

Comment: Ok, that's what I expected

Comment: I see no one said so, so I'll say it, this is called a sparse matrix representation, useful when most of the values are 0 (this is true in TFIDF since there are many more words than documents and most documents don't contain most words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first column contains the tuples `(ind_document, ind_word)` where `ind_document` is the index of your document (in your case a `string`) contained in your data set, and `ind_word` the index of the word in the dictionary of words generated by the `TfidfVectorizer` object.

The second column contains the TF-IDF value of your given `word` (the word corresponding to `(ind_document, ind_word)`.

---

**UPDATE**

If you look closer to the implementation of `TfidfVectorizer` [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html), you can see that there is a parameter called `norm`. By **default** this parameter is set to `l2` which is the L2-norm used to normalize the data obtained.

If you don't want to normalize your data and compare it to the results obtained manually **change this parameter** to `norm = None`

Comment: Thanks.

I have tried calculated TFIDF using formula given in website http://www.tfidf.com/

The result what i am getting by calculating with pen is different than what this TfidfVectorizer function is giving.

can you give an idea, why this difference ? if you have worked on this ?

As I searched in net, There is some L-2 normalization is done on the result. But i am not getting what exactly happening.